# How to connect two computers using R?

Tags: r, sockets, websocket, communication

Is it possible to open a communication stream between two R sessions on two different computers?

I use sockets to connect sessions if both are on the same computer. I suppose with two different computers, I should try web sockets. `httpuv` supports R as a web socket server, but unfortunately, I could not find any up-to-date package that supports a client web socket in R.

I'm not tied to using web sockets. Any solution that enables communicating between computers in a real time manner would work.

Comment: are you trying to do any cluster parallel computation? There is this package, `snow` that might be interesting to you https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Remote session on big memory machine? Clustering? MPI?

Comment: I'm not doing cluster parallel computation, however it might be similar in the communication concept. I'm trying to build something like a proxy server in R which get request from all clients and then it send them to a proper workers. My limitation is I cannot copy the original data from worker computers due to security reasons and also I could not get access to worker computers from outside networks. Therefore I assigned a computer in network to get client request, and send them to relevant workers with relevant data.

Comment: Ineresting. There are two **R** servers which you might try. One being from Rstudio folks (https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio-server-pro/), another from Microsoft (http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/01/microsoft-r-open.html). Not sure proxy itself is in any way to be done in **R**

Answer (score 1):

I have used [sockets](https://github.com/corynissen/r-socket-server) to communicate between computers using R.

server example:

```
import socket

server <- function(){
  while(TRUE){
    writeLines("Listening...")
    con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 6011, blocking=TRUE,
                            server=TRUE, open="r+")
    data <- readLines(con, 1)
    print(data)
    response <- toupper(data) 
    writeLines(response, con) 
    close(con)
  }
}
server()
```

client example:

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 6011))
while 1:
    data = raw_input ( "Enter text to be upper-cased, q to quit\n" )
    client_socket.send(data)
    if ( data == 'q' or data == 'Q'):
        client_socket.close()
        break;
    else:        
        data = client_socket.recv(5000)
        print "Your upper cased text:  " , data
```