# Using RStudio with R backend on cluster via SSH

Tags: r, rstudio

I have access to (not authority over) a computing cluster which has R installed. Is there a way for me to use R-Studio on my local computer -- but have the code running on the cluster via SSH?

To clarify -- No I don't really have non-SSH access, no I can't install R-Studio (server or desktop) on the cluster.

Comment: Not easily. There are some hacks/tricks that probably won't work if you can't install software. I'd see if you can get those who have authority over the environment to install RStudio Server or jupyter with the IRKernel.

Comment: Well, its been several years. Eventually I got the network admins to put in rstudio server. I never successfully got anything running prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

In line with the hackish options @hrbrmstr mentioned...

If your aim is to run mostly non-interactive code, then you can probably establish an n-node parallel::makePSOCKcluster() on the remote machines and run each of your commands via parallel like commands.  Similarly, you could use package::svSocket, [see this neat demo on YouTube for more details than fit in a reasonable answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvT8XThGA8o).

But, given that you said RStudio, I suspect you are thinking of interactive use, and the above would be doable (but painful).  Nothing I know of will let you just pretend that the remote machine is the local machine (which is a pity to be sure).  However you might be able to hack something together, with sink() etc and a server and client side loop, e.g. [How to connect two computers using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849356/how-to-connect-two-computers-using-r).